# Changing reference to different object without changing initially referenced object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm currently trying to write an XML-parser with the help of NSXMLParser. It's supposed generate an array of NSMutableDictionaries.

Making nested tags into nested dictionaries is really giving my brain a hard time. I might also note that I am very new to the language and this somewhat of an exercise for me.

## My actual question is:

Say I have an NSMutableArray called `xmlArray`. This is the array that in the end should contain all elements including sub-elements of the xml-file – as an array of nested arrays and dictionaries.

Now I might have another variable called `currentArray` that references a specific sub-array of `xmlArray`.

This might look something like this:

```
currentArray = [xmlArray objectAtIndex: 3];
```

Now I might want to reference a different part of `xmlArray` using `currentArray`.

So what happens if I then do this:

```
currentArray = [xmlArray objectAtIndex: 5];
```

Isn't this the same as saying:

```
[xmlArray objectAtIndex: 3] = [xmlArray objectAtIndex: 5];
```

**Am I switching my reference to a different object (`[xmlArray objectAtIndex: 5]`) or am I changing the initially referenced object (`[xmlArray objectAtIndex: 3]`)?**

**How can I change the reference to a different object without changing the initially referenced object?**

I'm aware that this is probably a really nooby question, I still hope someone might want to help. :) Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how variables work.

### What's going on?

`NSMutableArray* currentArray` is a variable, that will **hold** a *pointer* to the object we are dealing with. See the process of how this is used below:

This will get the pointer address of the object at index 3, and store it in current array:

```
currentArray = [xmlArray objectAtIndex: 3];
```

This will replace the value held in `currentArray` (which is only a *pointer*) with another pointer, this time to the object at index 5:

```
currentArray = [xmlArray objectAtIndex: 5];
```

The changing of the pointer within `currentArray` has **no** effect on the contents of the array itself.

This won't do anything either, as it's not resetting anything inside the array to change it's pointers at their indexes; it's just reading out of the array, not writing to it.

```
[xmlArray objectAtIndex: 3] = [xmlArray objectAtIndex: 5];
```

### As to your question...

> Am I switching my reference to a different object ([xmlArray objectAtIndex: 5]) or am I changing the initially referenced object ([xmlArray objectAtIndex: 3])?

You are switching your reference to the object, you are not changing the initial object. I highly suggest you read [Intro to Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html), as well as introduction to C style programming, as variable management is fairly fundamental stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! :)